# np.save for large data in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

As far I know `np.save` writes the array all at once outside the loop. Is it possible to put `np.save` inside the loop and save each row appending to a single file. The data I have is very large and if I declare an array of size `(200k X 20k)`, python crashes. I know the shape of the array.

## Sample code

```
for doPr in range(original_file.shape[0]):
    each_row = original_file[doPr, :]
    each_row = each_row + add_something
    np.save(path+"original_mod_file.npy", each_row)
```

`original_file` I read from hard drive row per row. `original_mod_file.npy` is what I want to write row per row and it will be of size `(200k X 20k)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: writing large array of arrays to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589583/python-writing-large-array-of-arrays-to-text-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [save numpy array in append mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30376581/save-numpy-array-in-append-mode)

Answer (score 1):

Copying from https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

```
with open('test.npy', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, np.array([1, 2]))
    np.save(f, np.array([1, 3]))
```

open the file you want to save to and edit the mode (`'rb'`) to `'ab+'`. This creates a file if it doesn't exists and let's  you append to it. You can then just append your data in a loop.